# Why do not agents go out from the queue?

Tags: anylogic

I have a queue,followed by selectoutput. the problem is that the agent does not go out from the queue.In this case the agent should choose the third exit of the selectoutput, so it is not possible (i presume)  that the agent does not go out because the following block is full.What could be the reason? Thanks
[image: error]

Comment: Check this blog post https://www.theanylogicmodeler.com/post/select-output-misbehaving

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PedSelectOutPut routing pedestrians inconsistently](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68733422/pedselectoutput-routing-pedestrians-inconsistently)

Answer (score 0):

the reason is that the condition that you think is true, is actually false, because anylogic calculates first the condition in the select output block, and then it runs the code on the "on exit" action of the queue7 block...

So my guess here, is that you are doing something on the on exit action, that changes the result for the condition.. but it's already too late..
use the "on at exit" action or sometimes you need to put a dummy delay of 1 milisecond or so between your last block before the selectoutput and the selectoutput to ensure your condition is met correctly

This is the order in which things happen:

1. on at exit queue
2. check condition
3. on exit queue
4. on enter select output

Comment: the action code is on enter, but even if no condition is true,why does not the agent go out on exit 5 (the exit when no condition is true)?

Comment: I'm sorry that my question was not clear. I found the problem anyway (the exit where the agent was supposed to go out was linked with a assembler's queue with 0 capacity.)Thanks for the help.